# PHP Telegram Bot running on Xampp Apache HTTP error

Tags: php, apache, server, bots, telegram

This is the error it gives me when I run it. Can someone please help me?

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=&text=default):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socializers_bot\index.php on line 30

```
  <?php

   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

 $botToken = "";
 $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);

$chatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$message = $update["message"]["text"];

switch($message) {

case "/test":
    sendMessage($chatId, "test");
    break;
case "/hi":
    sendMessage($chatId, "hey there!");
    break;
default:
    sendMessage($chatId, "default");

 }

 function sendMessage ($chatId, $message) {

$url = $GLOBALS['website']."/sendMessagechat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message);
file_get_contents($url);
 }

 ?>
```

I also Tried changing URL to CURL. `$curl`, `urlencode`... and it gave me another error.

Comment: `$url = $GLOBALS['website']."/sendMessagechat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message);
` it's wrong and need to be:-`$url = $GLOBALS['website']."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message);
`

Comment: I changed it and it still says the same error

Comment: `?` is the difference around `sendMessage`

Comment: hide your bot token plz;)

Comment: I changed it and it stills says the same error man

Comment: Your question appears to include an API token. If this was meant to be private, you should change your API token now.

Comment: I am just testing. Can someone please help me with my question?